# How can I load text file in javascript using fileReader?

Tags: javascript, file, filereader

I'm trying to load simple text file in javascript, unfortunately with no success.
my code is:

```
var my_text:any;
var my_file:File = new File([], "C:\\Users\\riki7\\Downloads\\classes.txt");
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
  my_text = reader.result;
};
reader.readAsText(my_file);
alert(my_text);
```

after this code runs, I would expect to see classes.txt file content in pop-up alert, instead I get 'undefined'.
my file contains a, b, c.

does anyone know what is my problem? maybe the first parameter for File() constructor?

Comment: `my_text` doesn't exist at the point you're trying to alert it. It hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: I edited my answer please check it it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use html tag `<input type="file" id="input" />` and then hung a event listener on it, like that

```
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
function handleFiles() {
  const fileList = this.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
}
```

then after simply bypass your file into the FileReader

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

And i guess that would be it.
You can find more examples there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications

Having your code where your `alert` runs upfront the callback function. If you need to see alter with the content, simply move your alert into the callback function:

```
reader.onload = function() {
  my_text = reader.result;
  alert(my_text);
};
```

because `my_text` is not ready when you call alert outside.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="file" id="selectedFile">
<p id="display"></p>
<script>
var fr = new FileReader();
let test;
document.getElementById('selectedFile').addEventListener('change', x);

    
function x() {
fr.onload = ()=>{
document.getElementById('display').innerText = fr.result;
test = fr.result;
alert(fr.result);


}
fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
}   


</script>
```

Comment: I pasted this code and got few errors.

Comment: I just create it new.html file and pasted my code it works fine, it seems like you tried code from console or idk, cause when I run it from console with document.write(\`code here\`)  it  gave error.

Comment: Worked fine when I used it

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
      var fileReadEvent = function(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(){
          var text = reader.result;
          alert(text)
        };
      };
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type='file' accept='text/plain' onchange='fileReadEvent(event)'><br>
    </body>
    </html>
```